# Create list of functions without eval/parse

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors of equal length `y`, `h` and `hp` defined as follows:

```
y  <- c(2, 5, 6)
h  <- c(4, 25, 35)
hp <- c(3, 10, 12)
```

The values are simply illustrative.

I want to create an output **list** `final_list` of functions in `x` as follows

```
function(x) y + (h - hp) * x
```

(only ideal illustrative output shown):

```
[[1]]
[1] function(x) 2 + (1) * x

[[2]]
[1] function(x) 5 + (15) * x

[[3]]
[1] function(x) 6 + (23) * x
```

I am aware that this can be done with eval/parse, but this does not produce transparent output for the functions.

I would like to create the functions from these 3 vectors and output without using eval/parse. If this is possible I would be really happy to learn and be impressed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Map()` with `substitute()`.  The middle expressions are not yet evaluated, but I don't think that's such a big deal.  They will be evaluated when the functions are called.  Basically we just assemble the function in parts.

```
funs <- Map(
    function(a, b, c) {
        f <- function(x) x
        body(f) <- substitute(y + (h - hp) * x, list(y = a, h = b, hp = c))
        f
    }, 
    a = y, b = h, c = hp
)

funs
# [[1]]
# function (x) 
# 2 + (4 - 3) * x
# <environment: 0x4543fd0>
#
# [[2]]
# function (x) 
# 5 + (25 - 10) * x
# <environment: 0x4549e20>
#
# [[3]]
# function (x) 
# 6 + (35 - 12) * x
# <environment: 0x454e5d8>
```

Now let's call the functions -

```
sapply(funs, function(a) a(1))
# [1]  3 20 29
```

**Note:** If you really need those middle expressions evaluated in the function bodies, you can use the following instead.

```
make <- function(a, b, c) {
    d <- b - c
    f <- function(x) x
    body(f) <- substitute(y + (e) * x, list(y = a, e = d))
    f
}

funs <- Map(make, y, h, hp)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
y <- c(2,5,6)
h <- c(4, 25, 35)
hp <- c(3, 10, 12)
fun_create <- function(y, h, hp){
  fun <- function(x){y + (h - hp)*x}
  return(fun)
}
out <- mapply(y, h, hp, FUN = fun_create)
```

The output doesn't give what you might expect but it works correctly:

```
> out
[[1]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x282ee40>

[[2]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x282e610>

[[3]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x282dde0>

> out[[1]](1)
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Just using the `function`-function will succeed if it is executed in the correct environment.

```
> mapply( function(y,h,hp) function(x){ y+(h-hp)*x }, y,h,hp)
[[1]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x7fb570828710>

[[2]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x7fb570823718>

[[3]]
function (x) 
{
    y + (h - hp) * x
}
<environment: 0x7fb57081b5c8>


> myfuns[[1]](x=1:10)
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
> 2+(h[1]-hp[1])*1:10
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

> myfuns[[2]](x=1:10)
 [1]  20  35  50  65  80  95 110 125 140 155
```

Each of those function definitions (actually closures)  carries along the first matching values that existed at the time of its creation when the interpreted traveled along the search path.

```
> environment(myfuns[[1]])[["y"]]
[1] 2
> environment(myfuns[[1]])[["h"]]
[1] 4
> environment(myfuns[[1]])[["hp"]]
[1] 3
```